# bat file which will rename all directories and files

Tags: batch-file, rename

I want to write a .bat file which will rename all directories and files. What I want to do is remove all characters after a specific character. For example my files are:
file1-312312
file2-421321321
etc.
What I want to have is:
file1
file2
So my specific characcter is "-".

I want to rename all of my files in a directory according to this. I want to help, thanks for your interest.

Comment: Have you done *anything* to try and figure this out yourself? A search here for `[batch-file] rename`, at least? All I see here is "Here's what I want. Be back later to pick it up. Thanks for doing my work. Bye.", and StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We expect at least some effort to solve the problem yourself first before posting here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

place batch file in the directory containing your files

@echo off

attrib ¦ find /c " ">filescount.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%c in (filescount.txt) do (

for /L %%n in (1 1 %%c) do (

for %%f in (*) do (

rename "%%f" "file_%%n%%~xf"

)

)

)